# Arrays & pureComputed values

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

According to [Knockout's documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html), one can use `pureComputed` to validate input fields.

The trouble seems to come when placing the observables bound to those input fields in an array (or observableArray).

```
this["values"] = []; // ko.observableArray([]);
```

And populating this array...

```
for(var $x=0; someArray[$x]!=undefined ;$x++){ 
  this["values"][$x]= ko.observable(someArray[$x]).extend(numeric: 0); 
}
```

Input fields are generated by KO's foreach, somewhat like this:

```html
<Table>
  <!-- ko foreach: generate_series( 1, field_Proyecto() ) -->
  <Tr><Td data-bind="text: 'Quota number: '+$data+':'"></Td>
  <Td><Input Type="Text" Class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: $root.fee_temp_data[$index()]"></Td></Tr>
  <!-- /ko -->
</Table>
```

Using the example "numeric" extender provided by Knockout, the inputs stay in "0" and performs no changes.

Using this, inputs are forced to be numeric, but when a users types a non-digit character, all the values in the array becomes empty ("").

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, option) {
  var to_number = ko.pureComputed({
    read: target,
    write: function(newValue){
      var current = target();
      $new = newValue.replace(/[\d]/ig, "");
      console.log($new);
      //$new = parseInt($new);
      //$new = $new.formatMoney(0, ".", ",");
      target( $new );
    }
  }).extend({ notify: "always" });

  to_number( target() );
  return to_number;
};
```

Also, "`^\d`" is supossed to match non-digits, but, as you can see I use `\d` and the code as is matches digits (in fact, you will see the console logs void values when integers are provided, but it will output the integer value in the input field).

`generate_series` simply outputs an array, given a range, also, this is the real function that initializes said observableArray.

```
this["generate_series"] = function($a, $b){

    this["fee_temp_data"] =[];
    this["fee"]( this["fees"][$b] );

    for(var $x=$a, $out=[];$x<=this["fees"][$b];$x++) { 
      $out.push($x); 
      this["fee_temp_data"].push( ko.observable("").extend( {numeric: ""} ) );
    }

    return $out;
  };
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4r1nv1ft/) to describe my problem.

Comment: pureComputed was introduced in ko 3.2.0, but jsfiddle only handles up to 3.0.0, so the fiddle doesn't run. Replacing pureComputed with computed and running 2.3.0 does run. (Knockout 3 is blocked for me on jsfiddle due to trying to use http in an https page.)

You do not need to put [\d] inside square brackets, and can use \D for non-digits.

Comment: There is a external resource in the fiddle that you should enable in your browser, the external resource is Knockout 3.3.0

Comment: Loading the jsfiddle page with http instead of https allows that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a call to `to_number` in the definition of `numeric` that was fouling things up. I've made an updated fiddle that removes non-digits and either updates the target or notifies subscribers (as per the documentation page): http://jsfiddle.net/4r1nv1ft/2/

Comment: Thanks!, i added that without thinking about it because the original function in the doc does that, my mistake. Mental note.